# Symfony 5 : install smalot/cups-ipp with composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, cups

I'm trying to install **smalot/cups-ipp** package on Symfony 5 but I have dependency issue with required packages.

To install **smalot/cups-ipp**, I run following command:

```
# composer require smalot/cups-ipp:dev-master
```

And result is:

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for smalot/cups-ipp dev-master -> satisfiable by smalot/cups-ipp[dev-master].
    - smalot/cups-ipp dev-master requires php-http/socket-client ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/socket-client[v1.0.0, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0, v1.4.0, v1.4.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried normal version (not dev-master) but I got another dependency issue with **symfony/yaml** package.

I installed **php-http/socket-client** which requires **symfony/options-resolver**.

**symfony/options-resolver** is in version 5 for Symfony 5. So I installed **php-http/socket-client** in dev-master version otherwise I have another dependency issue.

So now I have:

```
# composer show -i
symfony/options-resolver             v5.0.8
php-http/socket-client               dev-master
```

My problem is that **smalot/cups-ipp** requires **php-http/socket-client** in version 1.4, not version 2.0. So do you know how I can force **smalot/cups-ipp** installation with current **php-http/socket-client** package which is in dev-master (2.0) version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on https://github.com/smalot/cups-ipp/releases, there has been a release of that package just today. This update eases all package restrictions.

It is not yet available on Packagist, that's something that the maintainer must either configure through auto updates or trigger manually - until then, you have to wait.